# Is it possible to extensively customise embedded Google Maps to generate dynamic information?

Tags: google-maps, embed

What I would really like to do:

- Embed a google maps search box for users to enter their address, complete with the auto-complete/detect functionality available on Google maps so that they won't have to enter a full address.
- Calculate the distance from a fixed location (our warehouse) to the address they enter, and make this numerical information available for use in Javascript calculations.

It would be **incredibly** useful and rewarding for the company I work for, I can understand if it is indeed not possible but I really hope it is and welcome any and all suggestions..

I'm not asking for code, only resources where I can learn how to do this.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a special fancy map, you need to use Google Maps API.

You can learn about what Google Maps API is, please visit the official site.
https://developers.google.com/maps/